# How can I calculate a Bernoulli random variable that features retries?

Tags: probability

I have a situation modeled by a Bernoulli random variable with $p=0.4$, but with the added complication that five failures can be "rerolled" for the same probability. I can't use a binomial distribution on that, so how can I determine how many successes I'll get in a number of trials, say 20?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer! I used a binomial distribution to figure out how many successes and failures I would have. Then I chose 5 of the failures and figured that 0.4(5) of them would succeed after retry, and added that to the number of successes.